# What is the intuitive explanation for $\cos(\pi/4)^{2}- \sin(\pi/4)^{2}=0?$

Tags: trigonometry

For calculus we aren't meant to use calculators, however I couldn't get this one. Since I don't want to cheat myself I want to understand this intuitively before moving on.

Comment: What problem do you have with it? I really can't find out. If you want an intuitive approach, you must get through different books. **Spivak Calculus** would be the best to help out.

Comment: Perhaps the point of this problem was that you were supposed to recognize that $$\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = \cos 2x$$.

Comment: A recommendation is to make it one (or two, depending on the situation) trigonometric function either by dividing or adding things and then drawing a picture.

Comment: $\cos (\pi/2 - \theta) = \sin \theta$. If that's not intuitive enough, draw a circle.

Answer (score 2):

If you divide by $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2$ you get

$$1 - \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2}{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2} = 0$$
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \pm1$$

which is just an isosceles right triangle.

Answer (score 2):

This image is intuitive enough?
[image]

Comment: FWIW, your linked image is 404.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, I've linked a new image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2-b^2=0$ happens when either $a=b$ or $a=-b$; in this case we can show $a=b$, that is $\cos\pi/4=\sin\pi/4$. Use the Theorem $\cos(\frac\pi2-\theta) =\sin\frac\pi2$. This is also clear by using the ratios defining cosine and sine in a right-angled triangle; plain trigonometry, no calculus.

Comment: that is not a "Theorem", it is an identity btw.

Comment: Is there a law saying an identity cannot be a theorem?

Comment: I don't know, but a theorem is something that is not fully provable and still unprovable.  That is, if we are talking the quantum theory of light, someone can reject it and propose something else.  An identity is not arguable, it is a true statement, provably true and such.

Comment: Once you define sine and cosine in terms of right-angled triangles: we have two statements: $\sin^2\theta +\cos^2\theta =1$ and $c^2=a^2+b^2$. The first you would call an identity (as it is true for all angles $\theta$) and the second statement many people call Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: Good point.  I wonder why its only Pythagoras "theorem".  It is indeed true, and you can see it geometrically.  Thanks for the ideas.  Made me think.  ;D

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Draw a square. Draw a diagonal.

Now look at what you drew.

I think you can take it from here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/555741)

Comment: I think it's a perfectly reasonable answer. The triangles in the indicated diagram illustrate the given values of $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen     "I don't want to cheat myself I want to understand this intuitively before moving on". Please read to question before critiquing the answers. Please also note that this "critique" or "request for clarification" received an up vote from another user.